# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COLUMN'

Tags: sql-server

I am using sql server and i want to increase size of my column but it gives exception

```
    -- increase size of email type 
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AM_email_content]
ALTER COLUMN [email_type] VARCHAR(100);
```

Comment: your query is correct please show all code

Comment: Looks like you are highlighting the word "COLUMN" and executing, try executing the entire query.

Comment: add `NULL` or `NOT NULL` in the end of your query

Comment: select both lines of code and then execute, then let us know occuring error

Comment: your issue is resolve ?

Comment: Issue is resolved. Thanks to everone

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue in your Alter statement. It should work. Select your entire statement and then execute it in SSMS.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AM_email_content] ALTER COLUMN [email_type] VARCHAR(100);
```